# CompilationOutputs in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

Is there any similar property to CompilationOutputs in TFS 2010?
If not, how to get all compiled assemblies including all metadata as in TFS 2008?

Answer (score 0):

In TFS2010, if you use the UpgradeTemplate.xaml build process template you can keep your existing TFS 2008 based MSBuild proj files that use the CompilationOutputs property and continue building as per usual.

If you are using TFS2010 workflow based builds (i.e. DefaultTemplate.xaml or a derivative) then the approach will need to be somewhat different.  The workflow makes a call to an MSBuild activity internally in order to compile the solution and there is nothing in the properties for that task that returns the data you're looking for.

To work around the change, further down in the workflow there is an CopyDirectory tasks that moves files from the binaries folder to the drop location.  You could always put in your own workflow activities just before or around that point in the process and do what ever it is you are wanting to do.